# crawling into csv (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a little crawler (python, bs4) that works mostly fine. But if the text I want to crawl has more than two wordwraps (new lines) in a row, the content will be written in more than one cell.

For example:

AAA
BBB
CCC

The result into a cell of the csv is "AAA BBB CCC"

Bad case:

AAA
BBB

CCC

The result looks like this:
Cell 1: AAA BBB
Cell 2 (second row): CCC

The Code is:

```
...
        beschreibung_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-objektbeschreibung text-content short-text"}) or ""
        beschreibung = beschreibung_container[0].get_text().strip() if beschreibung_container else ""

        ausstattung_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-ausstattung text-content short-text"}) or ""
        ausstattung = ausstattung_container[0].get_text().strip() if ausstattung_container else ""

        lage_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-lage text-content short-text"}) or ""
        lage = lage_container[0].get_text().strip() if lage_container else ""
    except:
        print("Es gab einen Fehler")

    f.write(objektid + "##" + titel + "##" + adresse + "##" + criteria.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + preis.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + energie.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + beschreibung.replace("\n", " ") + "##" + ausstattung.replace("\n", " ") + "##" + lage.replace("\n", " ") + "\n")
...
```

Is there a possibility to replace all wordwraps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.sub to replace anything matching one or more newlines (`\n`) with a space in the desired strings:

```
re.sub(r'\n+', ' ', str)
```

If you need to replace carriage returns (`\r`) as well as newlines, you can use:

```
re.sub(r'[\r\n]+', ' ', str)
```

Here's how your code would change:

```
import re

...
        beschreibung_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-objektbeschreibung text-content short-text"}) or ""
        beschreibung = beschreibung_container[0].get_text().strip() if beschreibung_container else ""

        ausstattung_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-ausstattung text-content short-text"}) or ""
        ausstattung = ausstattung_container[0].get_text().strip() if ausstattung_container else ""

        lage_container = container.find_all("pre", {"class":"is24qa-lage text-content short-text"}) or ""
        lage = lage_container[0].get_text().strip() if lage_container else ""
    except:
        print("Es gab einen Fehler")

    f.write(objektid + "##" + titel + "##" + adresse + "##" + criteria.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + preis.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + energie.replace("    ", ";") + "##" + re.sub(r'\n+', ' ', beschreibung) + "##" + re.sub(r'\n+', ' ', ausstattung) + "##" + re.sub(r'\n+', ' ', lage) + "\n")
...
```

Comment: I will test this more if you can supply the complete source code and an example data file, or a minimal example of each that causes the problem. Otherwise I'd just be guessing. (e.g. you may also have `\r` splitting up your `\n` sequences, but I have no way of knowing that without seeing the data).

Comment: Here is the full example: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wz697k1vyogyvel/AAAlJS0PnJbzbHLK-3rkwHNoa?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks! Your data has carriage return characters in it (`\r`) as well as line feeds (`\n`). So the regular expression needs to be like `re.sub(r'[\r\n]+', ' ', ausstattung)` and so on.